# Working with XML, Root Node not creating

Tags: xml, vb.net

I'm fairly new to XML in VB and I'm looking to create a storage method for my 'Cards' program.

I'm creating a card creator that creates a new card within the cards node but for each card I want a card node to be created.

This is the module where the xml file is first created.

```
  Sub newCard(id, cardname, description, type, image)
    ' Create array of employees.
    Dim card As Card
    card = New Card(id, cardname, description, type, image)
    Dim settings As XmlWriterSettings = New XmlWriterSettings()
    settings.Indent = True
    Dim writeStart As Boolean
    If Not IO.File.Exists("C:\Godlycards\cards.xml") Then writeStart = True
    If writeStart = True Then
        Using writer As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create("C:\Godlycards\cards.xml", settings)
            writer.WriteStartDocument()
            writer.WriteStartElement("Cards") ' Root.
            writer.WriteStartElement("Card")
            writer.WriteElementString("ID", card._id.ToString)
            writer.WriteElementString("Name", card._cardName)
            writer.WriteElementString("Type", card._type)
            writer.WriteElementString("Image", card._image)
            writer.WriteElementString("Description", card._description)
            writer.WriteEndElement()
            writer.WriteEndElement()
            writer.WriteEndDocument()
        End Using
        MessageBox.Show("File created")
    Else
        AddXmlData(id, cardname, description, type, image)
    End If
End Sub
```

Here is the output (as you can see its clean and working):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Cards>
  <Card>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Name>Hello</Name>
    <Type>Typeee</Type>
    <Image>Imagehere</Image>
    <Description>Desccc</Description>
  </Card>
</Cards>
```

I started writing a module where an xml file is appended but rather than creating a card node it places it within the current card node.

```
   Private Sub AddXmlData(id, cardname, description, type, image)
    Dim myXmlDocument As New XmlDocument
    Dim myNodes, myChildren As XmlNodeList
    Dim node(5) As XmlNode

    myXmlDocument.Load("C:\Godlycards\cards.xml")
    myNodes = myXmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName("Cards")

    For Each n As XmlNode In myNodes
        If n.Name = "Cards" Then
            myChildren = n.ChildNodes
            For Each n1 As XmlNode In myChildren
                If n1.Name = "Card" Then
                    node(1) = myXmlDocument.CreateNode(System.Xml.XmlNodeType.Element, "ID", "")
                    node(2) = myXmlDocument.CreateNode(System.Xml.XmlNodeType.Element, "Name", "")
                    node(3) = myXmlDocument.CreateNode(System.Xml.XmlNodeType.Element, "Type", "")
                    node(4) = myXmlDocument.CreateNode(System.Xml.XmlNodeType.Element, "Image", "")
                    node(5) = myXmlDocument.CreateNode(System.Xml.XmlNodeType.Element, "Description", "")

                    node(1).InnerText = id
                    node(2).InnerText = cardname
                    node(3).InnerText = type
                    node(4).InnerText = image
                    node(5).InnerText = description

                    n1.AppendChild(node(1))
                    n1.AppendChild(node(2))
                    n1.AppendChild(node(3))
                    n1.AppendChild(node(4))
                    n1.AppendChild(node(5))
                    myXmlDocument.Save("C:\Godlycards\cards.xml")
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            Next
            node(0) = myXmlDocument.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Card", "")
            node(1) = myXmlDocument.CreateNode(System.Xml.XmlNodeType.Element, "ID", "")
            node(2) = myXmlDocument.CreateNode(System.Xml.XmlNodeType.Element, "Name", "")
            node(3) = myXmlDocument.CreateNode(System.Xml.XmlNodeType.Element, "Type", "")
            node(4) = myXmlDocument.CreateNode(System.Xml.XmlNodeType.Element, "Image", "")
            node(5) = myXmlDocument.CreateNode(System.Xml.XmlNodeType.Element, "Description", "")
            node(1).InnerText = id
            node(2).InnerText = cardname
            node(3).InnerText = type
            node(4).InnerText = image
            node(5).InnerText = description

            node(0).AppendChild(node(1))
            node(0).AppendChild(node(2))
            node(0).AppendChild(node(3))
            node(0).AppendChild(node(4))
            node(0).AppendChild(node(5))

            n.AppendChild(node(0))
            myXmlDocument.Save("C:\Godlycards\cards.xml")
            MessageBox.Show("Appended to file")
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Here is the output to this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Cards>
  <Card>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Name>Hello</Name>
    <Type>Typeee</Type>
    <Image>Imagehere</Image>
    <Description>Desccc</Description>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <Name>Hello</Name>
    <Type>Typeee</Type>
    <Image>Imagehere</Image>
    <Description>Desccc</Description>
  </Card>
</Cards>
```

Notice how it does not create a new card but uses the default node.
I'm fairly new to this and would appreciate any help!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following codes. I am assuming that `<Cards>` is root element of your XML, so there must be only one `Cards` element in XML (no more no less) :

```
Private Sub AddXmlData2(id, cardname, description, type, image)
    Dim myXmlDocument As New XmlDocument
    Dim myCards As XmlNode
    Dim newCard As XmlNode
    Dim node(4) As XmlNode

    myXmlDocument.Load("C:\Godlycards\cards.xml")
    myCards = myXmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName("Cards")(0)

    node(0) = myXmlDocument.CreateNode(System.Xml.XmlNodeType.Element, "ID", "")
    node(1) = myXmlDocument.CreateNode(System.Xml.XmlNodeType.Element, "Name", "")
    node(2) = myXmlDocument.CreateNode(System.Xml.XmlNodeType.Element, "Type", "")
    node(3) = myXmlDocument.CreateNode(System.Xml.XmlNodeType.Element, "Image", "")
    node(4) = myXmlDocument.CreateNode(System.Xml.XmlNodeType.Element, "Description", "")

    node(0).InnerText = id
    node(1).InnerText = cardname
    node(2).InnerText = type
    node(3).InnerText = image
    node(4).InnerText = description

    newCard = myXmlDocument.CreateElement("Card")
    For Each xmlNode As XmlNode In node
        newCard.AppendChild(xmlNode)
    Next

    myCards.AppendChild(newCard)
    myXmlDocument.Save("C:\Godlycards\cards.xml")

End Sub
```

The output will be about like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Cards>
  <Card>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Name>Hello</Name>
    <Type>Typeee</Type>
    <Image>Imagehere</Image>
    <Description>Desccc</Description>
  </Card>
  <Card>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <Name>randomCard</Name>
    <Type>randomType</Type>
    <Image>randomImage</Image>
    <Description>randomDesc</Description>
  </Card>
</Cards>
```